# View TFS server-side changes from within Visual Studio without getting latest version

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, azure-devops

In Visual Studio 2010, I want to able to view changes that other team members have checked-in without actually performing a get-latest (which would overwrite local files). Is there a way to do that for bulk files instead of selecting each file and comparing it to the server version?

Comment: How do you want to visualize all these files at once?  You can select an entire folder to compare to latest?

Comment: The idea wasn't to visualize the changes, rather get a list of files that are updated on the server and not locally. I was finally able to locate the folder comparison option from source control explorer rather than solution explorer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the View History window, then select any changeset and view the details, you can see each file that was included in that changeset and choose to Compare with Previous Version to see the specific changes.

[image: View History]
[image: Changeset Details]
[image: Compare With Previous]