# How do I know which files I actually changed since my last TFS checkout?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I've checked out a bunch of files from TFS in VS2010 and made changes to several of them.  How can I see which files I actually made changes to?

Comment: Maybe not the most convenient solution and I'm fairly sure there's a better way, but if I remember correctly, if you choose "Undo", you should see a list of changed files possible to undo. Same should go for "check in".

Comment: possible duplicate of [View TFS server-side changes from within Visual Studio without getting latest version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085822/view-tfs-server-side-changes-from-within-visual-studio-without-getting-latest-ve)

Answer (score 6):

Use the TFS power tools. Open a visual studio command prompt, navigate to your workspace and then type

`tfpt uu /noget /recursive`

This will undo any pending changes on files that haven't been modified

Answer (score 1):

Is `View -> Other Windows -> Pending Changes` what you are looking for? That lists all of the changes in your selected workspace that are pending a check-in. It looks (and behaves) differently in VS2010, but [here's what it looks like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245462%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#pending_changes) in VS2012.

Answer (score 0):

To add to hawkke's answer, I use CTRL-K C to show the pending changes window - very useful.

(hit ctrl-k and the then 'C' key right after).